# Answers offering to write code: Spam or NAA?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, not-an-answer

I came across a question where a user was asking how to accomplish a task (basically a search and replace) within a tool. One user, provided an answer that was basically

> I can write a program to do this for you

Not word for word, but pretty close. I wasn't sure whether to flag as spam (as he seems to be promoting a service, albeit his) or as NAA (that's certainly not an answer to the question) and I think I ended up going with spam.

In the future, what's the better option in cases like this?

Comment: I think "NAA" is a safer bet, unless he quotes rates or links to his service, or even if his service is advertised in his profile.  People are picky about what "spam" means on the network.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a link to the post. It is kind of hard to answer this without the specific context.

Comment: @Lundin not necessarily. Most likely, that answer is already deleted, so only higher reputation folks can see it. And worse, it might lead to people "punish" the person who made that offer.

Comment: It's not hard to find if you know how, but I agree with @GhostCat -- let's leave that sleeping dog lie.

Comment: @GhostCat It doesn't matter if it is deleted. The quoted part is very brief, so I doubt this was the actual answer. The "meta effect" is not a valid reason not to link it.

Comment: I was told differently more than once. And I also think this is more of a canonical question, so it works good enough with the specific answer it talks about.

Comment: Note that Stack Exchange's definition of spam is roughly "promotion without disclosing affiliation". Now, "I can do this for your", however, pretty obviously shows that the author is affiliated with the service, namely himself. So, according to that definition, it is not spam, since the fact that a person is affiliated to himself should be obvious.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - LOL, excellent point.

Answer (score 27):

This is worth checking the user's profile to see if this is something they've done multiple times. If they've already got multiple answers like this, flag for moderator attention and explain the problem. It won't be clear from spam flags that there are multiple offenses by the same user.

If there's no sign this has happened more than once then I agree with Dan Bron that Not An Answer is safer if there's no links, rates, or contact info for a service present. They do not want to treat someone who's just clueless about how the site works the same as someone promoting a commercial endeavor.

If they went and posted their *personal* contact information, that should also get a moderator flag as that needs to be scrubbed from the site.